# copy-history is actually copying 'copy-history'

Tags: ruby, pry

using the pry plugin : pry-clipboard

When I go to type 'copy-history' to copy the last line of my history, it literally is copying 'copy-history' and pasting 'copy-history'.

Am I missing something here?  Even when I feed it a range option its copying things that aren't even in my history...

```
[19] pry(RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyHelperModuleWorks)> copy-history
-*-*- Copy history to clipboard -*-*-
copy-history
[20] pry(RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyHelperModuleWorks)>
```

~~~~

```
[5] pry(RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyHelperModuleWorks)> history
1: puts "this is what I want to copy"
2: puts "this also should get copied"
3: puts "and this..."
4: puts "but we don't want this"
[6] pry(RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyHelperModuleWorks)> copy-history --range 1..3
NoMethodError: undefined method `<' for true:TrueClass
from /Users/MY_USR_NAME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/pry-0.10.1/lib/pry/code/code_range.rb:50:in `find_start_index'
[6] pry(RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyHelperModuleWorks)>
```

Answer (score 2):

I had same problem

```
[19] pry(RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyHelperModuleWorks)> copy-history
-*-*- Copy history to clipboard -*-*-
copy-history
[20] pry(RSpec::ExampleGroups::MyHelperModuleWorks)>
```

changing one line worked for me.

```
diff --git a/lib/pry-clipboard.rb b/lib/pry-clipboard.rb
index 146a003..2c643be 100644
--- a/lib/pry-clipboard.rb
+++ b/lib/pry-clipboard.rb
@@ -50,6 +50,7 @@ module PryClipboard
       end

       def process
+        #binding.pry
         history = Pry::Code(Pry.history.to_a)

         history = if num_arg
@@ -66,7 +67,7 @@ module PryClipboard
             n = history.lines.count if n > history.lines.count
             history.take_lines(-n, n)
           else
-            history.take_lines(-1, 1)
+            history.take_lines(-2, 1)
           end
         end
```

Comment: I have no idea what is the problem of "--range"

Comment: Works for me too https://github.com/hotchpotch/pry-clipboard/compare/master...andreikoenig:master

Kinda hoping someone was actively maintaining the gem